# Auto refresh from database across all instances

Tags: java, spring

In my java/spring application a database record is fetched at the server init and is stored as a static field. Currently we do a mbean refresh to refresh the database values across all instances. Is there any other way to programatically refresh the database value across all the instances of the server? I am reading about EntityManager refresh.Will that work across all instances?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have one database and several instances of the same application connection to the database?

What is the trigger to start the reload? Is it periodically updated?

Comment: Hi cmoetzing, thats right. one database and many instances. for the reload, the current system its a manual mbean load command. I am looking for options to remove the mbean by either a web command submit to reload or something like that

Comment: this sounds as some  config parameter which is grabbed from db and can be changed at runtime. in such case you can use  https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope.

Comment: The refresh scope sound very intersting. does it work for multi instances?

Answer (score 0):

You could [schedule](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) a reload every 5 minutes for example.

Or you could send [events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) and all instance react to that event.

Comment: Adding one more  [post to look](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/qcn.htm#TLADG1006). It is Oracle post about **Using Database Events to Invalidate the Cache**

Answer (score 0):

Till now, Communication between databases and servers is one-sided i.e. app server requests for data from the database. This generally results in the problem, and as you mentioned, that all application servers cannot know about a database change if an application is being run in cluster mode.

The current solution includes refreshing the fields time-to-time (A poll based technique). 
To make this a push based model, We can create wrapper APIs over databases and let those wrapper APIs pass on the change to all the application servers.

By this I mean, Do not directly update database values from one application server but instead, on an update request send this change request to another application which keeps track of your application servers and pushes an event (via API call or queues) for a refresh of the passed database table.

Luckily, if you are using some new database (like MongoDB), they provide this update push to app servers out of the box now.